# Same C++ 'if' statement, different results on Linux/Windows

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw, multiplatform

I've found an interesting case where the same C++ code yields different results on different system.

```
#include <cstdio>
int main()
{
    int a=20, b=14;
    if(a*1.0/b*(a+1)/(b+1)==2) printf("YES!");
    else printf("NO!");
}
```

Compiled on Ubuntu Linux 12.04 using GCC 4.6.3 it outputs **YES!**

Compiled on Windows 7 using GCC 4.6.2 it outputs **NO!**

However, using:

```
double  c = a*1.0/b*(a+1)/(b+1);
if (c==2) printf("YES!");
...
```

will return **YES!** on both machines.

**Any ideas why this difference emerges?** Is this caused by compiler version mismatch (pathlevel version number shouldn't matter THAT much)? And why does it actually output **NO!** on the Windows machine, while this condition is obviously true?

Comment: Floating Point!!!

Comment: What everyone should know about floating point arithmetic: http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Exact comparison with floatin point numbers is The Bad Idea

Comment: Remove the ".0" from the if and it will be the same for both.

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is only a guess, you would need to look at the assembly output from the compiler to know for sure.

It is possible that one compiler left intermediate results in a floating-point register while the other wrote the results to memory, rounding it from 80 bits to 64. It's also possible that one uses SSE and the other does not.

Comment: +1 (almost) everyone knows about FP issues but you tried to guess a **reason** for this difference!

Comment: Yes, exactly, thanks for suggesting a reason for this issue :-)

Comment: To clarify, 20/14 can be represented exactly using 80bit precision but not with 32 bit precision (not tried 64). The Windows build is storing intermediate values in RAM or using SSE whereas the Ubuntu build is keeping intermediate values in the FPU.

Comment: @Skizz, how is it possible that 80 bits would help? The fact that 14 isn't a power of 2 means the fraction will repeat infinitely.

Comment: @Skizz: 20/14 has a non-terminating expansion in base-2.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: You're right. The value is exact to 81bits (i.e. the value wasn't rounded up when stored at 80bits) but not exact at 33bits (i.e. it gets rounded up when stored at 32bits)

Comment: @Skizz, it's never exact no matter how many bits you use. I'm guessing that you mean rounded down vs. rounded up.

Answer (score 14):

Because you are doing an equality comparison on floating-point types, which in general should not be relied upon for particular bit-exact behaviour from machine to machine (or from compiler to compiler, etc.).

Possible reasons include the compiler's choice of when to move floating-point results out of wide (80-bit) floating-point registers (neither the language standard nor the IEEE-754 floating-point standard impose any particular requirements, AFAIK).

Comment: I think it would be interesting to know what attribute of the compiler or processor was responsible for the difference. IEEE floating-point should be consistent if not exact.

Comment: @MarkRansom: There is no guarantee on consistency as the numbers are not exact. Re-arranging the order of operations (that should mathematically be consistent) can produce different results just because of the accuracy of the values involved. The compiler only guarantees mathematical consistency not accuracy consistency.

Comment: @LokiAstari, gcc has a compiler switch to enable rearrangement of math operations when the result can't be guaranteed to match.

Answer (score 2):

it is because of floating point arithmetic, try using epsilon comparisions instead:

```
#define EPSILON_EQUAL(a,b) ( fabs((a)-(b)) < (0.0001f) )

float f = a*1.0/b*(a+1)/(b+1);
if(EPSILON_EQUAL(f,2.0f)) printf("YES!");
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting epsilon comparison, even if your answer does not explain why did this problem happen ;)

Comment: I suppose this has something to do with the fact that in first example you are using float ( in if statement ), in second example you use double. Here is SO that looks similar to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7702177/error-due-to-limited-precision-of-float-and-double

Answer (score 0):

because it is not correct to compare floating point numbers like that due to precision problems.

In mathematics 2/3= (0.6666666..... to infinity)//primary school math :) no questions asked.

In computing this calculation is carried out on the floating point unit (similar to CPU but is dedicated for floating point calculations). Now this floating point unit (FPU) may give you a number very close to your actual answer but they are not exactly the same. because it will truncate the results. There is an entire field dedicated to floating point arithmetic. In short never use floating point numbers in comparisons because you may get conflicting results.

Comment: This is true, but doesn't explain why it differs from platform to platform.

Answer (score 0):

Testing for equality between floating point numbers is problematic. This is because of rounding errors and there are many, MANY texts on this on the internet.

You can see this [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049101/floating-point-equality-in-python-and-in-general), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832592/test-for-floating-point-equality-fe-floating-point-equality), [here](http://discuss.fogcreek.com/joelonsoftware/default.asp?cmd=show&ixPost=161828), [here](http://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/11/they-sure-look-equal/) and basically any result in a google search for `floating point equality`.

Comment: This is true, but doesn't explain why it differs from platform to platform.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, like I said, there are a hell lot of texts on this. There is no point on explaining it yet another time in my opinion.