# Comparing doubles yields one less AND equal to the other

Tags: c, 32bit-64bit

So I have the following code:

```
 double which_min(const int i, const int j, const int nx,
                  const double step, const double local_cost,
                  double *D)
 {
      double tuple[3];

      // DIAG, LEFT, UP
      tuple[0] = (D[d2s(i-1, j-1, nx)] == NOT_VISITED) ? DBL_MAX : D[d2s(i-1, j-1, nx)] + step * local_cost;
      tuple[1] = (D[d2s(i, j-1, nx)] == NOT_VISITED) ? DBL_MAX : D[d2s(i, j-1, nx)] + local_cost;
      tuple[2] = (D[d2s(i-1, j, nx)] == NOT_VISITED) ? DBL_MAX : D[d2s(i-1, j, nx)] + local_cost;
      /*
      if (i == 83 && j == 124) printf("less? %d\n", tuple[1] < tuple[0]);
      if (i == 83 && j == 124) printf("equal? %d\n", tuple[1] == tuple[0]);
      if (i == 83 && j == 124) printf("greater? %d\n", tuple[1] > tuple[0]);
      */
      int min = (tuple[0] <= tuple[1]) ? 0 : 1;
      min = (tuple[min] <= tuple[2]) ? min : 2;

      if (i == 83 && j == 124) printf("min = %d\n", min + 1);

      return ((double) min + 1.0);
 }
```

For the problematic case I'm working with, when `step = 1`, `i = 83` and `j = 124`, I'm getting

```
min = 2.
```

However, if I uncomment the other `if` statements, I get the correct value of `min`, but...

```
less? 1
equal? 1
greater? 0
min = 1
```

I know comparing doubles can be finicky, and I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10519523/5793905) that mentions moving from 80-bit register to 64-bit memory, so I'm guessing the `printf` statements could be causing something like that. However,

1. It still feels counter intuitive that `tuple[1]` is both less AND equal to `tuple[0]`, how is that possible?*
2. Can I change this so that it gives the same result consistently?

And by the way, this only happens in a 32-bit system, the 64-bit version doesn't give me any problems.

EDIT: I guess that the first `printf` results in a loss of precision so that the `==` comparison evaluates to `1` afterwards, but still, the main question is whether I can make the result consistent.

EDIT2: Indeed, changing the order of `if` statements to

```
 if (i == 83 && j == 124)
 {
      printf("equal? %d\n", tuple[1] == tuple[0]);
      printf("less? %d\n", tuple[1] < tuple[0]);
      printf("greater? %d\n", tuple[1] > tuple[0]);
 }
```

Results in

```
equal? 0
less? 0
greater? 0
min = 1
```

And the values I get with `printf(%a)` are

```
tuple[0] = 0x1.2594a8056d275p+5
tuple[1] = 0x1.2594a8056d275p+5
tuple[2] = 0x1.fffffffffffffp+1023
```

Comment: "how is that possible?" Because of a compiler bug/non-srandard floating point arithmetic? What are your compiler and compilation flags?

Comment: Can you make a simple example with the exact values of tuple[1] and tuple[0]? Something like `double a = X; double b = Y; printf("%d %d %d\n", a < b, a == b, a > b);`

Comment: You can print out the doubles exactly with `printf("%a"`

Comment: Perhaps you are using a compiler option aimed at providing faster DP arithmetic at the cost of occasional anomalies such as you describe.  Several compilers offer such options.

Comment: As a comment to your edit. `printf` has nothing to do with this. There is no loss of precision. Printf receives an integer argument that's either 0 or 1, it is not involved in the comparison.

Comment: Consider also that it's a fairly serious problem for a computation to be sensitive to small differences between `double` values (relative to their magnitude).  Floating-point arithmetic is *inexact* by nature.

Comment: Since `printf` changes the behavior of of the comparisons later (the calculation of `min`) I'm more inclined to believe that the problem is a buffer overflow of the `D` array or something like that. Floating point numbers are not magic, they behave predictably even when the compiler is allowed to do more with them than most people think and they don't behave like numbers in school.

Comment: I assume the `printf` causes what the other link mentions, moving a value from a register to memory...

Comment: @Alexis yeah, I was just about to take that statement back. saving the value around the call to printf to the stack would also explain this behavior.

Comment: The key point here is that you are seeing behavior that appears to be inconsistent with the requirements of the standard.  Supposing that your program is not exhibiting undefined behavior -- from overrunning array bounds, for example -- that is not a problem that can be fixed in your code.  Very likely, such a problem has to do with optimizations performed by your compiler; that's why @n.m. and I both brought up your compile options.

Comment: The gcc flag you're looking for is `-ffloat-store`. But it makes floating point math horribly slow. Just say that the code is only supported on `amd64` and newer machines.

Comment: Very well, I will investigate about the compiler options, I actually don't know the values being used (I call the C code through R). I just wanted to make sure there is nothing I can do to account for this behavior.

Comment: Ideas to narrow the problem: 1) re-iterate: review FP compiler options 2) Use `volatile double tuple[3];` to force compiler to not use extended precision intermediate results  3) Use `int lt = tuple[1] < tuple[0]; etc.` to force (encourage) the compare computation to occur before all the `printf()`s.  4) Watch for `(lt + eq + gt) != 1`. IMO, either the issue is #1 or compiler bug or UB elsewhere in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed the results stored in `tuple` were being read with more precision than expected, causing some of the comparisons to yield contradicting results.

Adding the `-ffloat-store` flag to the compiler remedies the situation, but as mentioned in the comments, it might not be ideal, and apparently it isn't portable.

Declaring `tuple` as `volatile` seems to do the trick, but it had to be done as

```
volatile double *tuple = (double *)malloc(3 * sizeof(double));
```

And then

```
free((double *)tuple);
```

EDIT: apparently the above isn't necessary,
using `volatile double tuple[3];` is enough.
In order to use it only in x32 compilations,
I used the following `typedef` in `C++`:

```
#include <type_traits> // conditional
typedef std::conditional<sizeof(void*) == 4, volatile double, double>::type tuple_t;
tuple_t tuple[3];
```

Comment: Don't cast the result of `malloc()` and friends. It is unnecessary and can mask the absence of an appropriate prototype.